# After update to 21.04 my alias in bashrc no longer works

Tags: bash, kubuntu, bashrc, alias, konsole

I have appended this alias in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias libreoffice="flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable"
```

Prior to the update (from Kubuntu 20.10 to Kubuntu 21.04) this alias did work when I opened a terminal from [dolphin](https://apps.kde.org/dolphin/) (<kbd>F4</kbd>). It no longer does.
Any ideas?

Running `flatpak run org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable` in the terminal still works as expected.

**PS: The problem occurs only when invoking the terminal from Dolphin with <kbd>F4</kbd>. It does not occur in [konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) or guake. The alias works if defined manually in the terminal. Hence, it seems that since 21.04 dolphin no longer reads the bashrc file in its terminal.**

Edit: After closing the terminal session <kbd>Ctrl.</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> and reopening <kbd>F4</kbd> it does work. After reboot it does not.

Comment: Does `flatpak` still in your path? You could try `which flatpak` in order to find where the executable is and modify your alias.

Comment: @pa4080 it is. `/usr/bin/flatpak` and /usr/bin is in my path

Comment: Maybe you have a problem in an earlier line?  i.e., an unclosed quotation mark or something?

Comment: @Ray It looks fine (Kate has code highlighting so this would jump in the eye). Moreover, I do not recall having made any modifications other than appending the alias...months ago.

Comment: Is the alias shown in the output of `alias`? If not, it is not properly defined.

Comment: Please be more specific than "no longer works" - command not found? not executable? something else gets executed?

Comment: @steeldiver No longer works means that it returns libreoffice is not installed. Also note that if I manually run the alias, it works in that session, hence my problem is that it is not read in the .bashrc file.

Comment: @vanadium Indeed it does not show up in alias when run in the terminal of dolphin. It does show up in guake and konsole. But your inference is not very helpful. Of course if an alias does not work it means per definition that it has not been properly defined. The question is why.

Comment: I just added the line `echo "hello"` to my `~/.bashrc` while dolphin was open (without terminal pane). Opening the terminal pane doesn't display `hello`. Right click in the terminal pane and chose `close session`, the pane will be closed. Opening the terminal pane again now displays `hello`.

Comment: @mook765 Thank you, I can verify that after close session Dolphin picks up the .bashrc file. The strange thing is, it does not after a reboot.

Comment: @Bruni I still trying around and find the result is inconsistent, sometimes `~.bashrc` will be read, sometimes not. Wether I use F4 or menu item to open the terminal pane. I think we stumbled upon a bug.

Comment: @mook765 I opened this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/1929930